Are there any nice examples of problems in E / NE?
Let $E = DTIME(2^{O(n)})$ and $NE = NTIME(2^{O(n)})$ be the deterministic/nondeterministic complexity classes of problems decidable in exponential time with linear exponent.
There are many examples of problems "underneath" this class, in $P$ and $NP$, and there are many examples of problems "above" this class, in $EXPTIME$ and $NEXPTIME$. But it seems nice examples of problems that belong to $E$ or $NE$ are scarce.
What are some nice (natural, non-artificial) examples of problems in these complexity classes?

What about the most natural EXP-complete language ${\langle M,x,t\rangle|\text{$M$ decides $x$ in $2^t$ time}}$?
